# WebBrowser control: how to determine if access is denied to the URL?

Tags: webbrowser-control, access-denied

I'm hosting an instance of a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control in an application and the ASP.NET page this control is navigating to requires Forms Authentication.  I'd like to know within my application if the access to the web page had been denied either because the user entered an incorrect credential or because [s]he cancelled the credential input dialog.  Is this possible?  I've subscribed to both Navigated and DocumentCompleted events but see no indication of the 'access denied' condition.

Thanks much,  eugen

Answer (score 0):

Form authentication is implemented by the server. The user gets a web form to authenticate, and the response can be anything as the server programmer is free to code the response. The server programmer may return any HTTP status the programmer see fit, display an too-many-failed-attempt page, or show a database server down notice. There is no universal way to determine the login status.

Comment: Thank you. Where will I receive the response from the server please? Again, my scenario is that I have the WebBrowser control that navigates to some web page and want to know from within the WPF application that hosts the WebBrowser control that access to the web page had been denied.

Comment: Ask the server programmer, the webbrowser is just the middle man showing you what the server programmer has coded.

Comment: Thanks again!  Can you please suggest some ways the server can return the error response?  I am not an ASP.NET or web developer and all that is done in IIS for authentication is that "Forms Authentication" is enabled and from there on I could not find any code that does anything to that purpose, it appears as if the authentication with Active Directory just happens. Can you also suggest where I should look for authentication code in IIS 7?

Comment: Are you mistaking Windows authentication as Form authentication? Check the authentication setting as well as asp.net's web.config.